# Prevent Direct access to PHP file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to prevent direct access to a certain PHP file called `prevented.php`
My logic is that I have a main file lets call it `index.php` and it generates a token and stores it in a `$_SESSION` variable. I also have a another file called `def.php` which is called using AJAX and it passes the token from the `index.php` to the `def.php` and if the `$_SESSION['token']` is equal to the `$_POST['token']` it defines a `_DEFVAR` and returns true otherwise it returns false. After I called the `def.php` and it returns true, I redirect to the `prevented.php` via javascript using `location.href="prevented.php"`. In the top of the `prevented.php` file there is a code which checks if the `_DEFVAR` is defined or not. If not, its die with a message like `invalid` otherwise it displays the content of the `prevented.php` file. But somewhy I always get `invalid` message and I don't know why. Any idea how to reach the `prevented.php` without directly direct the page?

Here's my code:

`index.php`

```
<?php
  $_SESSION["token"] = hash_hmac('sha256', "tokenString", "t2o0k0e0n3"); // Creates a hashed token
?>
<script>
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "def.php",
      data: {
         token: '<?php echo $_SESSION["token"]; ?>'
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
          console.log (data);
          if (data) {
            console.log (data + ' valid');
          } else {
            console.log (data + ' invalid');
          }
          location.href = "prevented.php";
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log('error');
      }
   });
</script>
```

`def.php`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_POST['token']) || $_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['token']) {    
       echo false;
       die('invalid in def');
    } else {
      define('_DEFVAR', 1);
      echo true;
      die ('valid in def');
    }
?>
```

`prevented.php`

```
<?php
   include "def.php";
   if (defined('_DEFVAR')) {
    die ('valid in prevented'); // instead of this I would show the content of the page
   } else {
       die ('invalid in prevented');
   }
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? In the given code, you don't define `_DEFVAR`  anywhere in the `prevented.php`

Comment: The title of the question is completely different from it's description.

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry, updated it. I put a ```include "/def.php"``` so the ```prevented.php``` can see wheter the ```_DEFVAR``` is defined or not.

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Is the token sent properly using AJAX?

Comment: @NicoHaase It says its invalid in def, so I have some error in the ```def.php``` file I suppose but I have no clue what could the problem be.

Comment: Why do you need `def.php`? You could just send the token to `prevented.php` and it can check it against the session value of the token.

Comment: You don't even need the token, just drop a boolean flag in the session. The innate session cookie is already sufficient to determine ownership of the data. index.php creates the session and puts a flag in it, prevented.php only serves the page if the session exists and has the flag.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I have tried what you said, and it throws an error which says undefined index: token (the token is a boolean whis has a true value and in the ```prevented.php``` it check if the ```$_POST['token']``` is true or not )

Comment: Actually htaccess can ignore direct access to file or directory. `Order deny,allow Deny from all`

Comment: @Dlk you right, but if I deny it in the .htaccess I won't be able to reach the file via ajax..

Comment: Why does AJAX matter? Is your intent simply to allow access to `prevented.php` only when the person has first visited `index.php`?

Comment: @AlexHowansky My goal is if a user click on a button it should redirect to the ```prevented.php``` but if the user just type ```www.mysite.com/prevented.php``` it should throw an error like ```invalid request``` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is unnecessarily overcomplicated. If your intent is merely to ensure that visitors to `protected.php` have first visited `index.php` then all you need to do is create a session flag in one and check for its existence in the other. There is no need for any AJAX or any form POSTs. The innate behavior of PHP sessions already gives you this functionality.

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['flag'] = true;
?>
<a href="protected.php">click here for the protected page</a>
```

protected.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['flag'] ?? false) {
    echo "you have previously visited index.php";
} else {
    echo "you have not previously visited index.php";
}
?>
```

Comment: One thing I might add to this, is that a user could access `index.php` once and then visit `protected.php` directly as many times as they'd like. If this is a problem, you want to set the `$_SESSION['flag']` variable to false after checking for it